# queryui tabs widget presents url in brower status bar

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, web-applications

I am using the fine jQuery UI framework for developing a web-app style control panel.  It's supposed to look like a native app.  As such, I open the browser window in kiosk mode so that no extraneous browser features appear.  One difficulty I have encountered is that, since tabs are rendered as html anchors, the href for each tab appears in the status bar as "http://127.0.0.1/#main-tab", for instance.  This seems tacky to me and I seek a method for making it disappear.  I thought it would be considered a bug since, in this use case of anchor, it is not really branching to another site as they are typically used but the respondent did not agree.

At this point, I think I will have to find another means to solve the issue (monkey patch the jQuery UI code, perhaps? Ugh).

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

See the issue at the [demo page](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/).  Hover over the tabs to see that status bar change.

Comment: I don't see this as being a bug in any sense, just not your preference in this use case. I would suggest you research how to suppress this in the browser preferences itself for full screen mode. The other option is far more involved, and would require removing `<a>` from each of the tabs and building `.click()` bindings for each of the `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by customizing the `.tabs()` in a custom widget. Take a look.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/c315Lno4/3/

**CSS**

```
.ui-altTabs {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em;
}

.ui-altTabs .ui-altTabs-nav li {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.ui-altTabs-tab {
  float: left;
}

.ui-altTabs-anchor {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-altTabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  display: block;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.4em;
  background: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.altTabs", {
    _create: function() {
      this.wrapper = $("<div>")
        .addClass("ui-altTabs custom-altTabs ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content")
        .insertAfter(this.element);
      this.element.hide();
      this._createTabs();
    },
    _createTabs: function() {
      this.list = $("<ul>")
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .addClass("ui-altTabs-nav ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header")
        .attr("role", "tablist");
      this.content = [];
      var origSelf = this.element;
      var contentList = origSelf.find("ul li");
      var contentDivs = origSelf.find("div");
      var currentUiCount = $(document).find("[id^='ui-id-']").length;
      var self = this.list;
      contentDivs.each(function(ind, el) {
        var label = contentList.eq(ind).find("a").text();
        var target = $(el).attr("id");
        var item = $("<li>", {
          class: "ui-altTabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab",
          role: "tab"
        }).appendTo(self);
        $("<span>", {
          id: "ui-id-" + ++currentUiCount,
          "data-rel": target,
          class: "ui-altTabs-anchor",
          role: "presentation",
        }).html(label).click(function(e) {
          self.find(".ui-tabs-active").removeClass("ui-tabs-active")
          .removeClass("ui-state-active");
          $(e.target).parent().addClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active");
          contentDivs.hide();
          $("#" + $(e.target).data("rel")).show();
        }).appendTo(item);
        console.log("Appending Item to list: ", item);
      });
      self.find("li:eq(0)").addClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active");
      for (i = contentDivs.length; i--; i >= 0) {
        var panel = contentDivs.eq(i);
        panel.addClass("ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content")
          .attr("role", "tabpanel")
          .insertAfter(self)
          .hide();
        if (i == 0) {
          panel.show();
        }
      }
    },
  });
  $("#tabs").altTabs();
});
```

Comment: I finally got this mostly working in my application.  However, the sortable and select on hover functions of the new tabs do not work.  Also, the presentation is not the same as with the standard tabs widget even though I have modified my CSS to support the altTabs widget.  Can those functions be restored in the alternative?